# Android: Milestone and Galaxy have same resolution / dpi qualifiers for drawable, how to differentiate?

Tags: android, drawable, galaxy-tab, milestone, qualifiers

I'm developing an application that I'm testing on both the Motorola Milestone and the Galaxy Tab 10.1. My issue is that I'm trying to get my icons to scale properly by attaching qualifiers after the drawable folder name, and want the Milestone to use one set of icons, and the Tab to use another, but haven't found a unique combination to target either phone.

i.e. if I set my drawable folder to drawable-hdpi the Milestone and Tab both use the images in that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the screen size modifiers.  e.g. have two drawable directories:

```
drawable-normal
drawable-xlarge
```

See Table 2 in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for more qualifiers that you can try.

Comment: I tried that but I think that the Galaxy 10.1 is classified as large on Android systems earlier than v3.0 or something. I'm trying to just create one app that will properly scale to tabs or phones.

Comment: I don't believe there is anything earlier than Android 3.0 for the Galaxy Tab 10.1.  As far as I know only the original 7" Galaxy Tab had pre-Honeycomb (2.2).  You could try `drawable-large` if `drawable-xlarge` doesn't work.

Comment: yeah, you're right, sorry. I've been getting confused by reading all this qualifier / resolution / OS-specific stuff.                                                                                 Ok so I've tried this and it looks like it's working, thanks a lot. I changed the target of my app (in Eclipse properties) to 3.0, so it reads the xlarge screens in my android manifest file, but it still runs on the milestone.

Answer (score 1):

`drawable-hdpi` will target the Milestone (DPI = 240)

`drawable-mdpi` will target the Galaxy Tab 10.1 (DPI = 149)

You are mistaken that the Tab and Milestone are in the same DPI bucket.

For more information on how tablets and phones can be handled with res folders, see [this android developers blog post.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html)

Comment: interesting, this does seem to be the case. not sure why I thought it wasn't! but alas I still need to figure out a better way to identify resolutions via the qualifiers for my drawable folder...

Comment: Why do you need a better way to identify resolutions via qualifiers?

Comment: well basically I have the letters of the alphabet lined up horizontally, A-M, across the top of the screen (in landscape).                           as it stands right now, and it's working fairly well atm, is that in my drawable-hdpi folder, my icons are 50x60. these are displayed on the milestone. in the drawable-mdpi folder, the icons are 70x90, and are properly displayed on the Galaxy Tab.                                       my concern is with what's going to happen when the app is served on an mdpi phone? or an hdpi tab?

Comment: You're right; by having larger images in your mdpi folder, you're going to cause problems  on mdpi phones. In that case, it may be prudent to use @Joel F 's solution of putting images for tablets in the drawable-xlarge folder. I would suggest reading http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html

Comment: Thanks! I just came across that article. I'm currently using that method and it's working out well thus far. phew. Thanks for the help